# Can you determine the least degree of a morphism between algebraic curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I have several questions regarding the degrees of morphisms between algebraic curves.

1. If we have algebraic curves $X$ and $Y$ defined over some perfect field $k$, can we determine the least degree of a morphism defined over $k$ between them (we can assume we know that a morphism between them exists)?
2. Same question, but with $Y$ being an elliptic curve.
3. Same question, but with $X$ being the modular curve $X_0(N)$ and $Y$ being an elliptic curve with conductor $M \mid N$ and $M<N$ (for $M=N$ it is the modular degree).

If determining the exact least degree is not possible, methods to obtain lower bounds would be appreciated. For example, we can look at the number of points modulo $\pi$, where $\pi$ is a prime of good reduction for both $X$ and $Y$. We can also use the Castelnuovo-Severi inequality. What are the other methods?

Comment: Assume $X$ and $Y$ have genus at least two. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a non-constant morphism. Then $\deg f \leq (2g(X)-2)/(2g(Y)-2)$. This gives you an upper bound on the least possible degree.

Comment: (Same hypotheses on $X$ and $Y$.) The set of non-constant morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ is finite and "Effectively computable". So one could in practice compute the least minimal degree of a morphism from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: There is a work "Paulin Roland - On the minimal degree of morphisms between algebraic curves".

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar So there is an algorithm for finding the minimal degree? Where can I find it?

Comment: @PetarOrlic Not sure where to find it. Sorry. Also, I wrote "in practice" when I should have written "in theory". In any case, the set of maps of degree $d$ from $X$ to $Y$ is the set of points on a quasi-projective (finite) scheme.  You can use the theory of Grobner bases to check whether this scheme is empty or not once you have equations defining it. This can be done using the theory of Hilbert schemes.

Comment: I am not saying that this is a very useful algorithm...

Comment: When $Y$ is the projective line, the least possible degree is called the "gonality" of the curve and there is some literature on this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonality_of_an_algebraic_curve

Comment: @DamianRössler Actually that was the motivation for the question. I was studying the gonality of the modular curve X_0(N) and I am interested about results when $Y$ is an elliptic curve instead of $\mathbb{P}^1$.